# Reactfire: useFirestore().collection is not a functon

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, reactfire

I am having a bit of a fight with reactfire and its poor documentation.

I see many examples around using the apis coming from useFirestore() as if that was a normal firestore instance coming from the firebase SDK.

I see code like:

```
const firestore = useFirestore()

const myCollection = firestore.collection('collectionName')
```

But if I try to do that I get `firestore.collection is not a function`. Did something radically change recently or am I not getting something?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bad project structure. I give you my example:

```
// react-create-app structure

src --|
      |-- index.js
      |-- firebaseConfig.js
      |-- firebaseApp.js
      |-- App.js
      |-- ExampleComponent.js
```

Try it.

```
// src/index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Your firebase app info file

```
// src/firebaseConfig.js
const firebaseConfig: Object = {
  apiKey: 'xxx',
  authDomain: 'xxx.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'xxx-project',
  storageBucket: 'xxx.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'xxx',
  appId: 'xxx',
  // measurementId: 'xxx', // I don't enable google analytics for this project
};

export default firebaseConfig;
```

Example a FirebaseApp file

```
// src/firebaseApp.js

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/functions';
import 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'; // Your firebase app config

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default app;
```

Next file is App.js

```
// src/App.js

import React from 'react';

import { FirebaseAppProvider } from 'reactfire';
import firebaseApp from './firebaseApp'; 

import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <FirebaseAppProvider firebaseApp={firebaseApp}>
      <ExampleComponent />
    </FirebaseAppProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Component example code:

```
// src/ExampleComponent.js

import React from 'react';

import { useFirestore } from 'reactfire';

    
const ExampleComponent = () => {
    const firestore = useFirestore();
        
    console.log(firestore.collection('your_collection_name')); // Working good
        
    return <>Hello reactfire App</>;
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I think you have a bad project structure